# Adding an imported PDF to a table cell in iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I am creating a new PDF that will contain a compilation of other documents.

These other documents can be word/excel/images/PDF's.

I am hoping to add all of this content to cells in a table, which is added to the document - this gives me the goodness of automatically adding pages, positioning elements in a cell rather than a page and allowing me an easier life at keeping content in the same order as i supply (such as img, doc, pdf, img, pdf etc)

Adding images to the table is simple enough.

I am converting the word/excel docs to PDF image streams. I'm also reading in the existing PDF's as a stream.

Adding these to a new PDF is simple enough - by way of adding a template to the PdfContent byte.

What I am trying to do though is add these PDF's to cells in a table, which are then added to the doc.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use `Image.GetInstance(PdfTemplate template)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please download [chapter 6 of my book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf). It contains two variations on what you are trying to do:

- [ImportingPages1](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=110), with as result [time_table_imported1.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter06/time_table_imported1.pdf)
- [ImportingPages2](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=111), with as result [time_table_imported2.pdf](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter06/time_table_imported2.pdf)

This is a code snippet:

```
// step 1
Document document = new Document();
// step 2
PdfWriter writer
    = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
// step 3
document.open();
// step 4
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(MovieTemplates.RESULT);
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
PdfImportedPage page;
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
    table.getDefaultCell().setRotation(-page.getRotation());
    table.addCell(Image.getInstance(page));
}
document.add(table);
// step 5
document.close();
reader.close();
```

The pages are imported as `PdfImportedPage` objects, and then wrapped inside an `Image` so that we can add them to a `PdfPTable`.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the in depth answer.  That's spot on.

Comment: @Bruno Are we converting page object into real image?

Comment: @Maris your question is wrong. What is a *real image*? Are you claiming that vector images aren't real images??? Where you say "real image", you probably mean "raster image", and then the answer is: *"Of course not! It would be stupid to degrade a vector image to a raster image!"* Also: this question is old. It's dates from 2015 and iText 5. Today, we have iText 7, and the syntax is completely different. Please abandon iText 5, and upgrade to iText 7!!!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie The code looked a bit suspicious to me cause we are converting a page into image. That why I've asked that question. Is there any way to insert page into a cell directly without converting it into the image? For instance I would strongly disagree if someone, in html, will convert div element into image just to append it into td.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have collected the metrics it doesn't convert page into real image. Most likely it is just a bad code design of developers of the library. Nvm, it works, thank you for your answer.